# Powershell using hashtable and foreach loop to set appsettings via appcmd

Tags: powershell

I am trying to modify the web.config of a site by adding several appsetttings. To make this code more reusable and whatnot I would like to use a hashtable to store the key-value pairs and then loop over them. I am getting errors when trying to inject the key and value into the call to appcmd. Here is my code:

```
$env:myWebsite = "myWebsite"
$appcmd = "C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"

$settings = @{
    "test1"="C:\Temp\test";
    "test2"="true";
    "test3"="C:\Temp\"
}

foreach($s in $settings.GetEnumerator()){
    & $appcmd --% set config "%myWebsite%" /section:appSettings /+"[key='$($s.Name)',value='$($s.Value)']"
}
```

When I try and execute this it is not injecting s.Name and s.Value

Comment: Maybe check out the `WebAdministration` module instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/set-webconfigurationproperty?view=win10-ps

Comment: Hey @MathiasR.Jessen, thanks for the reply. The issue isn't with appcmd, if I don't try to use replacements this method works great. I'm certain the issue is with my crappy powershell skills.

Comment: Fair enough. If you want to have the `$(...)` subexpressions expand, you'll need to remove the `--%` modifier

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen, that solved my problem.

Comment: "%myWebsite%" expanded properly? Interesting.

Comment: @DougMaurer, I'd be lying if i said I understood more than half of what this script is doing, my powershell skills are lacking severely. That said; removing `--%` seems to have done the trick for me

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen may I ask you why you didn't answer this question? It seems it would've been beneficial for OP and others to know *why* removing --% would help. I'm just curious based on the points you and adminofthings made on the other post?